# Run class file using cmd commands

Tags: java, command-line

How can I run a class file using a java program with cmd commands?

Comment: What do you mean 'with cmd commands'? Can you provide examples?

Comment: @user496789: Please follow [general question guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, are you asking how to run java classes within java? If so, take a look at the Runtime class.

Like so:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec( /*params here*/ );
```

I would suggest using [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) version (using a String array), as I've had the best outcomes with it.

Comment: s.. ok if u got some idea please share it

Comment: I've just added more info to it.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the above comment in a code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

From your command prompt, type

`java classname`

where classname is the name of your compiled class.  Note that the class must contain a `main` method.

Comment: not in the cmd prompt but by using cmd commands inside my java program